# Visualize lambda logs with grafana?

Tags: aws-lambda, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a use case where i need advice from you.

I have written a lambda which pings google.com. This lambda is being trigerred every minute by cloudwatch rule. In cloudwatch logs i am getting 200 OK every minute.

Now i have to visualize this  in grafana.  Cloudwaatch is already added as a datasource

Only challenge i am facing is how to visualize lambda logs? I only get option of seeing no. of invocation count etc for lambda.

Lambda Code:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import http.client
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
    conn.request("HEAD","/index.html")
    res = conn.getresponse()
    print(res.status) 
    print(res.reason)
```

Comment: Should i write my output of lambda to influx DB? and then probably add influx db as datasource to grafana

Comment: Using influx first and then having grafana pull from that sounds like a better approach.